# The definition of a coroot for non-split reductive groups?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a connected, reductive group over a field $k$, and $A_0$ a maximal split torus of $G$.  Let $\Phi = \Phi(G,A_0)$ be the set of roots of $A_0$ in $G$.  Then the $\mathbb R$-linear span $\mathfrak a_0^{G \ast}$ of $\Phi$ in $\mathfrak a_0^{\ast} = X(A_0) \otimes \mathbb R$ is a root system.  Then in the dual space $\mathfrak a_0^G$ of $\mathfrak a_0^{G \ast}$ we have a set $\Phi^{\vee}$ of coroots.  By definition, the coroot $\alpha^{\vee}$ associated to a given root $\alpha$ is the unique linear functional on $\mathfrak a_0^{G \ast}$ such that

$$s_{\alpha}(x) := x - \langle x, \alpha^{\vee} \rangle \alpha$$
is a reflection on $\mathfrak a_0^{G \ast}$ which sends $\alpha$ to $-\alpha$ and permutes $\Phi$.

If $A_G$ is the split component of $G$, there is a canonical injection of $\mathfrak a_G^{\ast} = X(A_G) \otimes \mathbb R$ into $\mathfrak a_0^{\ast}$, such that $\mathfrak a_0^{\ast} = \mathfrak a_G^{\ast} \oplus \mathfrak a_0^{G \ast}$.  We then extend each element of $\mathfrak a_0^G$ to a linear functional on all of $\mathfrak a_0^{\ast}$, by setting it to be zero on $\mathfrak a_G^{\ast}$.  Thus the coroots are elements of $$\mathfrak a_0 = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb R}(X(A_0) \otimes \mathbb R, \mathbb R) = \operatorname{Hom}(X(A_0),\mathbb R) = X^{\ast}(A_0)$$
When $G$ is split, there is a very nice way to describe coroots, without reference to reflections or root systems.  Namely, if $\alpha \in \Phi$, and $T_{\alpha} = (\operatorname{Ker} \alpha)^0$, then $\alpha^{\vee}$ is the unique cocharacter of $A_0$ satisfying:

> (i): $\langle \alpha, \alpha^{\vee} \rangle = 2$
>
> (ii): The group generated by $T_{\alpha}$ and the image of $\alpha^{\vee}$ is all of $A_0$.

Suppose that $G$ is not split.  Is there any nice way to characterize the coroot $\alpha^{\vee}$ as in the split case?

Comment: In the second sentence, do you mean $A_0$ instead of $T$? Also I do not understand the sentence after that, where the notation $\mathfrak{a}_0^{G_*}$ is unclear to me; I am quite sure that an $\Bbb R$-linear span of whatever cannot be a root system though. Some thing seems to be in a wrong order there.

Comment: (1) Yes I meant $A_0$ instead of $T$ (2) The notation $(\mathfrak a_0^G)^{\ast}$ is standard for the linear span of the roots in $\mathfrak a_0^{\ast}$, in Arthur-Selberg trace formula stuff they use the fact that there is a canonical direct sum decomposition $$\mathfrak a_0^{\ast} = \mathfrak a_G^{\ast} \oplus (\mathfrak a_0^{G})^{\ast}$$where $\mathfrak a_G^{\ast}$ is the dual real Lie algebra of the split component of $G$.  Yes, the pair $(\mathfrak a_0^G)^{\ast}, \Phi$ is definitely a root system.